# How to add css class and id in @Html.TextBox mvc4 at the same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add css class and id in @Html.TextBox mvc4 at the same time.
I try

```
@Html.TextBox("name", new { id = "name"}, new { @class = "text-field" })
```

but as result I get

```
 <input class="text-field" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="{ id = name }">
```

I dont need attribute value here.
I need to get

```
 <input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name" class="text-field" />
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Correct [overload method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    Object value,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

you want to use `id` as HtmlAttribute, so you should use it in HtmlAttributes object. Correct usage of `TextBox` is:

```
@Html.TextBox("name", 
    null,
    new { 
        id = "name", 
        @class = "text-field" 
})
```

if you place `id` in route object, then id will be a route value.

Comment: Do I need to correct `public static MvcHtmlString TextBox` ? Where?

Comment: No, first code block is MVC textbox element method. I wrote it to show you. You should use, second code block...

Comment: First code block is the structure of one of overload method in MVC architecture.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
@Html.TextBox("name", 
    null,
    new { 
        id = "name", 
        @class = "text-field" 
    })
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got `<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="{ id = name, class = text-field }">`

Comment: Add the missing second parameter, didn't have the documentation at hand :)

Comment: @Heidel: I think AliRiza's answer should be marked as it is more comprehensive and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I simply use the **new** keyword. For example see the following code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Venue, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "AnyCustomID" })
```